# "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" using shallow list [:]

Tags: python

I tried with `[:]` in lists but still doesn't work

```
for bullet in self.bullets[:]:
    bullet.update(self.bullet_speed, self.bullets)
    for obstacle in game.obstacle_manager.obstacles[:]:
        if bullet.rect.colliderect(obstacle.rect):
            game.obstacle_manager.obstacles.remove(obstacle)
            self.bullets.remove(bullet)
            bullet_flag = True
            break
    if bullet_flag:
        break
```

it gets the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`
in `self.bullets.remove(bullet)`

I am looking for colision between bullets and obstacles if that happens the bullet and the obstacle should destroy

full function

```
def update(self, game):
    bullet_flag = False
    if game.player.type == WEAPON_TYPE:            
        if self.bullet_step%5 == 0:
            self.bullets.append(Bullet(game.player))        
        self.bullet_step += 1
    for bullet in self.bullets[:]:
        bullet.update(self.bullet_speed, self.bullets)
        for obstacle in game.obstacle_manager.obstacles[:]:
            if bullet.rect.colliderect(obstacle.rect):
                game.obstacle_manager.obstacles.remove(obstacle)
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
                bullet_flag = True
                break
        if bullet_flag:
            break
```

It seems that all answer point to use `[:]` so I hope you can help me since that didn't work or I'm not doing it right

Comment: Is `bullet.update()` capable of removing a bullet from the list?  (I assume that's why you're passing `self.bullets` as a parameter.)  If so, you still check it for collisions, and possibly try to remove it from the list again.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. I think Jason's on the right track, but we can't confirm without seeing the whole code of course.